# How efficient is making a JS request every 15 seconds to a Rails method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a method which checks for notifications and executes a `js.erb` in return.
The JS which is triggering this method is given below:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/checkNotification",
    type: "GET"
  });
}, 15000);
```

This is working great but I am worried about the performance of the site once it will be in production.
Will this cause a performance issue? 
If yes, is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Each of your users making an extra request (with a small request body and small response body) to the site every 15 seconds should not significantly increase the load on your website.  Compared to a full pageload it could well be 1% as big.  Therefore, it would be equivalent to each user marking an extra full pageload every (15 x 100) seconds , which comes out as every 25 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one suggestion I would make is to take advantage of the callback function of ajax so that if a request takes longer than expected it will not fire again until the last one completes

```
function checkNotifications(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/checkNotification",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(){
            setTimout(checkNotification, 15000);
        }
    });
};
```

also if for some reason the server were to respond with a 500 error, it would prevent the function from continuing